# Add versioning to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called ods.CustomerId

```
Create Table ods.CustomerId(
ScreenDate INT NOT NULL,
CustomerNum nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
MainAccountNum nvarchar(40) not null,
ServiceNum nvarchar(40) not null,
StartDate datetime not null,
EndDate datetime not null,
UpdatedBy nvarchar(50) not null);
```

I have a default constraint on the table for the StartDate as Getdate()

data that may be inserted may look like:
20190906,234567,340892567,12345892,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000, null,User

How can I add the version on to this table where when the customerNum is changed because of a mistake it assigns an enddate and also a version number such as like 1,2,3 and so on. So if the CustomerNum is not changed I do not want it to have an endDate. If the customerNum does change I want it to have an enddate and also the version. Can someone please provide examples of what this code would look like? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: for things like this I use a trigger that stores the old version of a row in another table, but your SQLServer might also be able to do row versioning automatically

Comment: "when the customerNum is changed because of a mistake" - how you detect the change reason? What if the other reason is detected?

Comment: @CaiusJard do you mind providing some code of what this may look like? I have even seen people using union to do it but I am not sure that I understand that method. They basically do an insert into table then the columns and the select columns in table then union the select columns again.

Comment: @Serg This is no method of tracking why it is being changed except we assume that it was a mistake say by typing the customerNum wrong or something.

Comment: `EndDate datetime not null,` + "So if the CustomerNum is not changed I do not want it to have an endDate." then at least allow NULL.

Comment: To have a history of an object this object must have an identity. What is a primary key of the table?

Comment: @Serg what if I had a left join in a storedproc that loads this table and inside the leftjoin is a and statement that says AND EndDate IS NULL AND a.CustomerNum=b.CustomerNumber. how could I include the logic within this join where I give an end date if the CustomerNum changes and if it doesn't I leave the endDate as null

Comment: @Serg there is a primary key cluster for the ScreenDate, MainAccountNum, ServiceNum, and StartDate

Comment: Rewrite your question, show all relevant object definitions and code.